# Worker pool implementation to limit http requests per second

Tags: go, worker-pool

I am new to Go lang and am trying to implement restrained GCP API calls. i.e. to limit the number of API calls per second my app makes, so Google won't block me.

I've been following the worker pool pattern exemplified [here](https://golangbot.com/buffered-channels-worker-pools/).

A design in a fashion similar to the linked example would be:

- make two channels (jobs, results) of capacity the same as the total number of API calls to make
- create a worker pool of a certain size (say 10 workers)
- each worker goes through the jobs channel while making API calls, and storing responses into the results channel, with 1 second waiting period

My questions are:

- am I understanding things correctly, that 10 workers each having a 1 second waiting period means my app makes approximately 10 API calls per second?
- how do the 10 workers communicate with each other so they don't step on each other's toes, i.e. two workers don't query the same GCS path.

And of course the ultimate question: is it an overkill using worker pools?

Thank you!

Comment: If you can breach the API rate limit with a single goroutine, then there's no point in using a worker pool.  What is the API rate limit?  What is the time for executing a request?  See https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/time/rate if you do need to limit the rate.

Comment: @CeriseLimón, thanks for the link! It's getting the size of objects in GCS, of which there could be tens of thousands. I'm seeing that there's a rate limit of 5K per second, according to https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-rate

Comment: That article does not state that there's a rate limit. It says that "you should ramp up your request rate gradually for any bucket that hasn’t had a high request rate in several weeks or that has a new range of object keys" and "if your request rate is expected to go over these thresholds, you should start with a request rate below or near the thresholds and then double the request rate no faster than every 20 minutes." Since you're paying for every request a hard rate limit would be weird.

Comment: @Peter, When I started using the app that didn't have any rate limit, I get errors like "dial tcp lookup storage.googleapis.com no such host", Googling around seems to suggest I am being limited by GCP. No?

Comment: No. Your DNS server is unreachable or malfunctioning or something like that.

Comment: @Peter. I'm not sure how to interpret this, but I went ahead with the solution I put in the question, and the same input which consistently generated that dial-tcp error went through fine. Maybe the worker pool implementation solved the DNS server issue? It's strange that my coworkers are seeing that as well. I don't know...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can implement a Throttler using Sync.Mutex and time.After something like below

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "sync"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)

type Throttler struct {
    invocations int
    duration time.Duration
    m sync.Mutex
    max int
}

func (t *Throttler) Throttle() {
    t.m.Lock()
    defer t.m.Unlock()
    t.invocations += 1
    if t.invocations >= t.max {
        <-time.After(t.duration) // This block until the time period expires
        t.invocations = 0
    }
}

func main() {
    t := &Throttler{
        max: 2,
        duration: time.Second,
    }
    // Launch your workers passing in the throttler created above.
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Println("starting worker")
        go Worker(t);
    }

    // This just to prevent the main from exiting.
    c := make(chan os.Signal)
    signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGTERM)
    <-c // This will block until you manually exists with CRl-C
}

// worker
func Worker(t *Throttler)  {
    t.Throttle()
    fmt.Println("Work done!!")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. My solution  in the question seem to be working, so I'll stick with that for now. ( I didn't make the downvote...)

Comment: Oh no worries about the downvote. I was just curios about your question and thought this is one way to implement a throttler.